# String.Format, Currency, Polish Złoty

Tags: wpf, format

I am developing an e-commerce administration panel in WPF. I would like to display currency values in PLN (Polish Złoty). Format {0:C} gives output in USD ($1.000). Is there a way to change this behaviour or do I have to write my custom format to accomplish this?

edit:
Why this is so if my windows culture info and location are both set to Polish/Poland?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to pass CultureInfo in your String Format.

```
string money = String.Format(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("pl"), "{0:C}", 30.7m);
Console.WriteLine(money);
```

EDIT: if you are in WPF then this should do the trick:

```
this.Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage("pl");
```

or

```
FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FrameworkElement), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(XmlLanguage.GetLanguage("pl")));
```

Comment: If I were using String.Format that would be easy, but my code looks like this:

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=OrderShippingInclTax, StringFormat=\{0:C\}}" /> The code is obviously XAML, this is why I'm asking about WPF not C#.

Comment: Thx. "this.Language" - what "this" means here?

Comment: In this case it is the window. You can do the same thing also in an another FrameworkElement.

Answer (score 0):

You sholud add only `xml:lang="pl-PL"` in your `<Window>` tag in MainWindows.xaml. Simple as that!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).